# Applying VBA script from single tab to all tabs when part of coding is tab dependent?

Tags: vba, excel

I created the below VBA script using something I found on this site and need some help making it better.

The end goal is to have users put in the name of the firm only once and have the filter and delete rows run on all tabs at once. For now you have to do it once on each tab, which can be time consuming. I found that the deleting hidden rows part of the VBA script (which I found here on SO) ran really quickly, which was really good given how large some of the sheets I'm using this on are, but is there a way to make this run for all tabs at once?

Again, I'm very much a newbie with this and so I used what I found, which is why it may say activesheet in the filtering but not in the deleting. Only because I couldn't figure out a smarter way to do this, and would appreciate the help.

```
Sub FilterByFirm()

' FilterByFirm Macro



ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$QP$8000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
"UBS Global Asset Management"

Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRows As Range
With Sheets("3")
Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End With

For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = oRow
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
    End If
End If
Next

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about running it on all the tabs (you mean worksheets, yes?) in the Workbook, but you can certainly loop through all the workbooks and run the sub.

Again, this is for if you want to run that macro on all sheets int he workbook.

Before the main part of your macro, the part that you want to run on each sheet, add this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' Do whatever you need on the sheet
Next ws
```

So, if I understand what you want correctly,

```
Sub test()
Dim ws      As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Range("$A$5:$QP$8000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="UBS Global Asset Management"
    Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRows As Range

    'With Sheets("3")

    With ws
        Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
        If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With

    For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
        If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = oRow
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next oRow

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried running what you wrote here instead of my own and got the following error: "Compile error: For control variable already in use" and it has highlighted the For Each Ws In under 'With Sheets (3)' And yes I did mean all worksheets when I said tabs, sorry!

Comment: Ah whoops - sorry, I updated the code.  For that AutoFilter, do you want that to also run on each sheet? Or just the first one?

Comment: Thank you! It should run on each sheet. The idea is that on all sheets I want it filtered down for (in this case) UBS, and then delete all the rows that are not UBS. Is the updated/edited version of your code above good for this? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, I've updated the code - the AutoFilter should run on each page.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain in the a**... Now I'm getting an End With without With error at the last End With. Not sure why

Comment: Ok let me try once more. Still getting the End With without With

Comment: Still getting the End With without With (just adding this comment here in case you didn't see- and again can't thank you enough)

Comment: Updated, sorry I missed that last `end with`.  Should be ok now.

Comment: Still not perfect- am getting Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class Failed and it's highlighted  the row with UBS written in it (I can confirm that UBS does appear in the sheet in that column in case that's the issue)